# How to access variables from controller in layout/main.php Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I am trying to access $searchModel from inside of main.php with this code:

```
<?php 
$form = ActiveForm::begin(['action' => ['search'],'method' => 'get','class'=>'lockscreen-credentials']); ?>
    <?= $form->field('searchModel', 'subject')->textInput(array('placeholder' => 'Title...'))->label(false); ?>
    <?= Html::submitButton('Search', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); 
?>
```

But i am getting the following error:

```
Call to a member function isAttributeRequired() on string
```

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong? and if possible provide a brief example of the correct way to do it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used is as string, but it should me variable:

```
<?= $form->field($searchModel, 'subject')....
```

Comment: Sorry my bad I should have spotted that. However now I am getting:

`Undefined variable: searchModel `

Which I thought would be solved using:

`<?= $form->field($this->params['searchModel'], 'subject')....`

But then I get:

`Undefined index: searchModel`

Comment: You have to pass this on your action: `$this->render('myView', ['searchModel' => $searchModel];` or define it in view if its layout file

Comment: Thank you for the quick answers. I should have added the controller action too shouldn't I - I do pass it to the action however I am trying to access it in the layout. So I pass the variable to the index view, how would I define it so I can access in layout? Sorry if I am missing something completely obvious. The exact same piece of code works inside of post/index.

Comment: In layout you have to define it exacly like in controller :) just it have to be before using it :)